# Updating div from selection with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to show or hide a div based on a selection from a list. I'm not quite sure how to handle the observable for the div being passed to a function so it can return a true or false value to show or hide the div.

If "American Express" is selected from the list, I want to display the "postalCodeDiv", otherwise hide it.

I have a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDRvM/)

```
<label for="Card Type">Card Type</label>
    <select data-bind='value: cardType, options: $root.cardTypeList, optionsText: "type"'>
    </select>       

<div data-bind="visible: postalCodeDiv()">
    <label for="PostalCode">Postal Code (required for AMEX)
    </label>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
function cardTypeSelection(cardType,postalCodeDiv){
    var self = this;
    self.cardType = cardType;
    self.postalCodeDiv = postalCodeDiv;


    if(self.cardType == "American Express"){
        return self.postalCodeDiv(true);
    }
    else{
        return self.postalCodeDiv(false);
    }

}

function MakePaymentViewModel(cardType) {
    var self = this;

    self.postalCodeDiv = ko.observable(false);

    self.cardTypeList = [
        {type: '-'},
        {type: 'Visa'},
        {type: 'MasterCard'},
        {type: 'American Express'}
    ];

    self.cardType = ko.observableArray([
        new cardTypeSelection(self.cardTypeList[0], self.postalCodeDiv)
    ]);

}

ko.applyBindings(new MakePaymentViewModel());
```

And upon selection of it, I pass it to a function to enable/disable based on the value of the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can have it much easier than you tried. not quite sure why you try to store the selected value from the dropdown into an array, you could just store the selected value into an observable and toggle the div visibility upon this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/infantrash/ZDRvM/2/)

**ViewModel:**

```
function MakePaymentViewModel(cardType) {
var self = this;

self.cardTypeList = [
    {type: '-'},
    {type: 'Visa'},
    {type: 'MasterCard'},
    {type: 'American Express'}
];

self.cardType = ko.observable(self.cardTypeList[1]);

}

ko.applyBindings(new MakePaymentViewModel());
```

**HTML:**

```
<label for="Card Type">Card Type</label>
<select data-bind='value: cardType, options: $root.cardTypeList, optionsText: "type"'>
</select>       

<div data-bind="visible: cardType() == cardTypeList[3]">
    <label for="PostalCode">Postal Code (required for AMEX)
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I was just basing this off of one of the examples from the knockout website, so I wasn't quite sure what I was doing either!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer provided by @infadelic, here is an example using a computed observable.  If you need this logic in more than one place, you may want to put it in your viewModel as a computed observable instead of having the logic repeated in multiple bindings.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ymwN/12/

**ViewModel**

```
function MakePaymentViewModel(cardType) {
var self = this;

self.postalCodeDiv = ko.observable(false);

self.cardTypeList = [
    {type: '-'},
    {type: 'Visa'},
    {type: 'MasterCard'},
    {type: 'American Express'}
];

self.cardType = ko.observableArray([
    new cardTypeSelection(self.cardTypeList[0], self.postalCodeDiv)
]);

self.selectedCardType =  ko.observable();

self.isAmex = ko.computed(function(){
    var card = self.selectedCardType();
    return card == 'American Express';
});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="Card Type">Card Type</label>
    <select data-bind='value: cardType, options: $root.cardTypeList, optionsText: "type", optionsValue: "type", value: selectedCardType'>
</select>       

<div data-bind="visible: isAmex()">
   <label for="PostalCode">Postal Code (required for AMEX)
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm sure this will come in handy in the future.